# Filter rows of 1st Dataframe from the 2nd Dataframe having different starting dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-processing

I have two dataframes from which a new dataframe has to be created.
The first one is given below.

```
data = {'ID':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C','C','C','C', 'D','D','D'],
    'Date':['2021-2-13', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-15', '2021-2-16', '2021-2-17', '2021-2-16', '2021-2-17', '2021-2-18', '2021-2-19',
           '2021-2-12', '2021-2-13', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-15', '2021-2-16','2021-2-17', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-15', '2021-2-16'],
   'Steps': [1000, 1200, 1500, 2000, 1400, 4000,3400, 5000,1000, 3500,4000,5000,5300,2000,3500, 5000,5500,5200 ]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1
```

The image of this is also attached.

[image: DataFrame 1]

The 2nd dataframe contains the starting date of each participant as given and shown below.

```
data1 = {'ID':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Date':['2021-2-15', '2021-2-17', '2021-2-16', '2021-2-15']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df2
```

The snippet of it is given below.

[image]

Now, the resulting dataframe have to be such that for each participant in the Dataframe1, the rows have to start from the dates given in the 2nd Dataframe. The rows prior to that starting date have to be deleted.

The final dataframe as in how it should look is given below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.merge` + boolean-indexing:

```py
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"])

x = df1.merge(df2, on="ID", suffixes=("", "_y"))
print(x.loc[x.Date >= x.Date_y, df1.columns].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Prints:

```
  ID       Date  Steps
0  A 2021-02-15   1500
1  A 2021-02-16   2000
2  A 2021-02-17   1400
3  B 2021-02-17   3400
4  B 2021-02-18   5000
5  B 2021-02-19   1000
6  C 2021-02-16   2000
7  C 2021-02-17   3500
8  D 2021-02-15   5500
9  D 2021-02-16   5200
```

---

Or: If some `ID` is missing in `df2`:

```py
x = df1.merge(df2, on="ID", suffixes=("", "_y"), how="outer").fillna(pd.Timestamp(0))
print(x.loc[x.Date >= x.Date_y, df1.columns].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `ID` in df2 is unique, you could map df2 to df1, compare the dates, and use the boolean series to index df1 :

```
df1.loc[df1.Date >= df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('ID').squeeze())]

   ID       Date  Steps
2   A 2021-02-15   1500
3   A 2021-02-16   2000
4   A 2021-02-17   1400
6   B 2021-02-17   3400
7   B 2021-02-18   5000
8   B 2021-02-19   1000
13  C 2021-02-16   2000
14  C 2021-02-17   3500
16  D 2021-02-15   5500
17  D 2021-02-16   5200
```

Comment: Nice solution with `.squeeze`. And grats to golden python badge ;)